# How Entity Framework and Authentication(OWIN Middleware) fit in a Large multi tenant Business Application Design

Tags: authentication, entity-framework-6, multi-tenant

We have a large multi tenant business application and we want to know how Entity Framework and Authentication will fit in this design; i mean i need samples on how to use Entity Framework in this design and how authentication will be done; i see Dynamics Crm and sharepoint use Configuration(Master) Database and different databases for each tenant; how the users will be authenticated and saved;when i investigate dynamics crm configuration database, i see it contains users table; also, the tenant database contains Users table and i don't know the difference

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad and may require a lot of detail to go into. I would like to give you a simple overview.

The Entity Framework & OWIN Middleware's are one way of easing in the development effort. You choose EF when you ONLY have a object model that is similar to that of your database.

The advent of OWIN middlewares help you to easily integrate with a wide variety of authentication mechanism like Google, Facebook, Azure Active Directory etc...

Additionally, in addition to using OWIN, you will still require to build a logic around the user and tenant management systems. There will be a tenant table that contains the metadata about your tenant's [customer's].

There will be a user table that will contain your user's against tenant's. Here, each row can be identified against a tenant using tenant identifier or you can opt to use a separate table for each tenant.

The single database model is the one which is shared by all the tenant's and is belonging to the Level 4 of Multi-tenancy.

You should decide based your business specific use case whether you need to support a shared database or a dedicated database per tenant.

With OWIN, I have also written middlewares that can talk to any OAuth2 enabled IDP and get back the user into the system. It is upto the business usecases which drive the level of customization and depth of integration required and the technologies just help us achieve the same.

Please share some more specific questions or your views to discuss further

Comment: Thanks for your help but i want examples with code and best practices for these issues; i already use separate database for each customer and a master configuration database but i want to know how the authentication will be performed as many multi tenant Microsoft apps use users table in both the configuration and tenant databases such as Dynamics Crm and sharepoint